# set miltiset удаление добавления

Tags: c++, stl, set, multiset

Написал код удаления-внесения элементов в сет, но после удаления первого элемента выдает ошибку, помогите понять, что не так

```
void Minimal(multiset<int>& mySet)
{

    int temp3 = 0;
    int temp4 = 0;
    int temp5 = 0;

    for (auto& item : mySet)
    {
        if (item < temp3)
        {
            temp3 = item;
        }
    }
    cout << endl <<"Минимальное число = "<< temp3 << endl;
    for (auto& item : mySet)
    {
        temp4 = item;
        mySet.erase(temp4);
        temp5 = temp4 - temp3;
        mySet.insert(temp5);

    }

        cout << "==============================================================================" << endl;
        cout << "Результат: ";

        for (auto& item : mySet)
        {
            cout << item << " ";
        }
        cout << endl << "==============================================================================" << endl;

}
```

Comment: Вот такой цикл 

    `for (auto& item : mySet)`

опирается на итераторы, а вызов `erase` инвалидирует итератор, указывающий на текущий элемент. В таких циклах добавление-удаление - это очень стремная операция, которую в общем случае применять нельзя. Вы сформулируйте свою сверхзадачу, может, ее можно решить попроще (например, если вы в свой `multiset` не передали какой-то хитрый компаратор, то минимальный элемент - это просто первый...

Comment: Да он первый, мне то и нужно из каждого элемента мультисета вычесть минимальный элемент, но сделать это можно только удалением и записыванием нового элемента, из которого уже вычли минимальное значение. Но никак не получается.

Comment: тем более что вы удаляете temp4, а потом пытаетесь его использовать

Comment: Если не секрет, а почему именно `multiset`? Если нужны такие длинные операции - может, тот же вектор подошел бы лучше? Что еще вы делаете с мультисетом?... И, мне кажется, что у вас проще даже создать новый и присвоить старому, нет?

Comment: @Harry Задание дали сделать это именно в сете, поэтому и морочусь теперь

Comment: Можно пройтись по элементам, вычитать каждый элемент и вносить в новый мультисет, после чего просто выполнить присвоение. Проще, а с учетом того, что они все остаются сортированными, можно итератор из предыдущей вставки использовать как подсказку для следующей - если мультисет достаточно умный, это позволит ускорить работу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так не хотите?

```
void Minus(multiset<int>& m)
{
    if (m.empty()) return;
    int min = *m.begin();
    multiset<int> v;
    for(int i: m) v.insert(v.end(),i-min);
    m = v;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    multiset<int> m;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)  m.insert(rand()%90+10);

    for(int i: m) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;

    Minus(m);

    for(int i: m) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, как я сам не додумался до этого...

Comment: не  думаю, что нужно так, думаю задание именно для проверки знаний  как добавлять и удалять в том же контейнере